# Firefox Sync - how to change "Main Computer" for an existing account

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I no longer have the PC which I setup with Firefox Sync as the "Main Computer".

I would like to assign a different PC as the "Main Computer" to which other computers/devices are paired as per this Firefox Help page [How to sync Firefox settings between computers](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20sync%20Firefox%20settings%20between%20computers)

How may I assign a different PC as the "Main Computer" for my **existing** account?

Comment: Related: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/924238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to [reset your Firefox Sync account and add all devices again](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Replace%20your%20Sync%20information):

> At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button (Tools menu in Windows XP) and then click Options
>   Once the options window opens, click on the Sync tab.
>   In the Sync tab click on Manage Account and select My Recovery Key.
>   A new window will open displaying a Recovery Key - ignore that and click Generate a new key.
>   A new Recovery Key will be made for you. Please take a moment to print it out or save it on your computer. Then click Change Recovery Key
>
> You should see two status messages. The first one will say, "Changing Recovery Key and uploading local data, please wait..." and the second one will say, "Your Recovery Key was successfully changed!".
>   Once your Recovery Key has been changed the window will close.
>   Note: This first sync should happen quickly but may take more than 30 minutes, depending on how much information needs to be synced.
>   Click OK to close the Options window
>
> Now that you've changed your Recovery Key, any devices you had connected to your Sync account will stop syncing. You'll have to re-add them to your Sync account by following the steps in How to sync Firefox settings between computers or How do I sync Firefox between my desktop and mobile?.

Comment: thank you - that looks like it - I'll give it a try from my new "Main Computer" this evening and revert :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "main computer" on Sync!
You can pair new devices from any computer on which Firefox Sync is already set-up. As soon as you paired a new computer, it can act as a pairing machine (thus a "main computer") too.

I don't have the original "main computer" that I used to set-up Firefox Sync. I wiped the hard disk and reinstall the OS since that time. And I think I even don't own this computer any longer...

But I have no problem pairing new devices from the miriad of installation of Sync I have around.

:)